# get data from ajax with POST

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, rest

right now I am stuck on a problem. I guess it is a very basic thing. But after doing researches for hours it would be great if someone can give me a quick advice.
So I am trying to call my PUT method from my api (C#)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public String Post(String id)
    {

        return id;
    }
```

It is called when i press a button. The button function is this:

```
<script>
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/values',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'id':"100014"},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
    });
}
```

If I call the GET method everything works fine. But trying to call the POST method it only returns that the resource is not supported for HTTP Post. 
I tested the method with Postman. Here the Post method works. 
But I do not want to pass these data into the Url but into the data from Ajax.

It would be great if someone can help me out.

**EDIT:**
I just tried some stuff. My final result is this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(int id)
    {
        var rawMessage = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Ok(rawMessage);
    }
```

It worked out for me fine.

Comment: You need to show more information in the view. In the controller you need to save the changes.

Comment: Try changing the signature of the handler to this... `public String Post([FromBody] String id)`

Comment: I am not from C# background, but I see that you are trying to send json data and catching it in String. Is that allowed? Try sending just the id value. Like `data: "100014"`. You probably need to change the contentType & dataType as well.

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` remove this as you are not sending any json. You might use `dataType: 'text',`

Comment: @Archer you are wrong. I do a test, without your [FromBody], the method is still called. Don't just click downvote other answers as you like. My solution works for my test.

Comment: @anhtv13 Your posted answer has nothing to do with the problem.  The problem is in the controller, not the Ajax request.

Comment: @lucas I don't mean to sound crazy, but is your controller method signature actually, `public String Post(String id)`? Are you routing the url `/api/values` to that function? Because by default, I think this would be looking for a controller called `api` and a method called `values`.

Comment: The browser consol returns this: jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST http://localhost:56644/api/values 405 (Method Not Allowed). Do I have to change any settings?

Comment: What type of project is this - MVC, WebApi?  Is this a System.Web.Http.ApiController or some other type of controller?  How are you defining the routing?  There are a LOT of quite small things that could make a world of difference and it's difficult to help without knowing more (as you can see from all the guesses that have been posted)

Comment: @lucas As per my last comment: Assuming MVC (if not, could you please specify your project type): If the URL you're trying to call from AJAX is `/api/values`, with the default routing conventions in place, this will never reach a method called `Post`. If your controller is called `api`, try renaming the URL of your AJAX request to `/api/Post`. The 405 error is a bit vague, but I think it's probably because the method you were using to test your GET request was called `values`, and it doesn't have the `[HttpPost]` filter. Is this conceivable, or am I way off base?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you route is not found.
Try

```
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("getValues")]
public String Post(String id)
{

        return id;
    }
```

You can even add before controller class:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
```

and then call it with

```
url: '/api/values/getValues',
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you referenced the correct library.

If you're using `System.Web.Mvc` this issue might occur. Trying removing that and referencing `System.Web.Http` instead.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your output with `Ok()` method . Something like

Use your returm type as `IHttpActionResult`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(String id)
    {

        return Ok(id);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should convert a JavaScript object to a string with JSON.stringify().
You can modify your method in script like this.

```
<script>
function sendData() {
var obj = { id:'100014'};
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/values',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

By the way, I see your path is incorrect. It should be `/api/post`

Comment: Data is automatically stringified, and the problem is nothing to do with the data.  It works if OP uses GET instead of POST.

Comment: @Archer I added the JSON.stringify(obj) and my test works. I don't understand why you downvote my answer???

Comment: You do not have to stringify data for Ajax calls.